# Conditions for Fault-tolerant QC to work better than not doing any EC (except the ideal decoder)

Tags: quantum-gate, error-correction, quantum-circuit, fault-tolerance

I've been exploring fault-tolerant QC with the simplest 7-qubit Steane code, yes I'm able to obtain all the predicted thresholds for various transversal gates and the EC gadgets. I then tried to stitch them up in a full circuit according to [AGP05](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0504218.pdf), e.g.
for a CNOT-exRec we have the following structure (CNOT is implemented transversally and the EC I use here is Steane's Fault-tolerant EC, prepare one logical 0 ancilla to check for X syndrome followed by a logical + ancilla to check for Z syndrome)

```
EC --I -- EC
     |
EC --X -- EC
```

and yes I'm able to obtain a threshold (~4x10^-4) in my case. But then I found that if I remove these EC gadgets (only the transversal CNOt) I actually end up with a higher threshold ... so I'm in sort of a dilemma here. I examined my codes and could not find any mistake, but on the other hand this doesn't make sense ... not doing EC is better than putting the gadgets here.
I suspect it's because the circuit is too short, error correction has yet to show its power, I'm wondering if there's any literature regarding circuit length for EC to work. Or what else could possibly go wrong?

Update: I checked out this paper [Ciaran et al. 22](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2208.01863.pdf), which realizes EC procedure on actual hardware. At the end of page 7 it makes the claim that not putting EC gadgets actually performs better. which I guess is similar to the result I obtained ...

Comment: Can you turn AGP05 into a link to the paper, and describe what the EC gadget is actually doing? There's lots of different gadgets out there.

Comment: @CraigGidney Thanks I updated my question. and I briefly thought about this ... if I have error rate p (for 1 CNOT). Then the logical error rate for transversal CNOT would roughly be 1 - 7p(1-p)^6 - (1-p)^7  (more than one error it goes wrong). I plotted this and it crosses the y=x line at around 0.05-0.06 ... seems to be a much higher threshold

Comment: Can you show the actual operations being executed both with and without the gadgets? Without the gadgets is there any error correction at all? How are you computing a threshold at all if there's no EC?

Comment: @CraigGidney I do have an ideal decoder at the end. so for testing out CNOT-exRec I do ECx2 -- CNOT -- ECx2 -- ideal decoder. Without EC I just remove those ECs in between. Since I wanted to use these exRecs in my circuit, I test them first.

Comment: Answering the question probably requires looking at the details of what you are doing, so you probably need to include the exact series of gates being performed for anyone to spot the problem.

Comment: @AndyLiuin I am not sure to understand how you can compute the threshold if you do not have error-correction. If you remove the EC-box you surely have less fault-locations in your circuit, but you also do not do any error-correction, so the notion of threshold loses its meaning. I may have completely misunderstood what you are doing though!

Comment: @MarcoFellous-Asiani Thanks I get what you mean. Basically I'm comparing the following two schemes. 1. CNOT-exRec + ideal decoder(which is an ideal final EC). 2. CNOT + ideal decoder. I think this is the standard way of running one error correction procedure ... Conclusions from my simulations are that the CNOT-exRec is not working better than not putting the ECs around CNOT. CNOT-exRec does provide some lower bound for the threshold though. Please point out if any of my understandings are wrong

Comment: @AndyLiuin Could you clarify a bit your "CNOT+ideal decoder" example? Do you mean that you simulate a transversal cNOT, where there is a probability $p$ to introduce either an $X$ or $Z$ error on each physical qubit after the gate, followed by an ideal round of error-correction? If that's the case, I think it means you are computing an error correction threshold, not a fault-tolerance threshold, meaning that you assume that error-correction is perfect. In such a case it is normal that your "threshold" is much higher.

Comment: You can take a look at my post here to understand better why really the full exRec is relevant: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/23917/analytical-approximation-of-pseudothreshold-for-steane-code/24056#24056